# Historically who started to define conic sections in terms of foci and directrix?

Tags: soft-question, conic-sections, math-history, locus

There are no definite references - but I have only been able to trace back to Pappus and possibly Aristaeus, a contemporary of Euclid. I'm trying to piece together the path to our current taught definitions of conic sections in terms of foci and directrix.

[Here's](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/Biographies/Aristaeus.html) the best reference/citation I have found so far:

> Heath makes a guess at the possible contents of the Solid Loci and
> writes [3]:-
>
> A very large portion of the standard properties of conics
> admit of being stated in the form of locus theorems ... But it may be
> assumed that Aristaeus's work was not merely a collection of the
> ordinary propositions transformed in this way; it would deal with new
> locus theorems not implied in the fundamental definitions and
> properties of the conics, such as ... the theorems of the three- and
> four-line locus. But one (to us) ordinary property, the focus
> directrix property, was, as it seems to me, in all probability
> included.

This implies that they were *probably* known to Aristaeus and since there was a tendency to define stuff with reference to *loci* of points, Aristaeus found a way to define conics that way. But, he had to introduce a notion of a directrix when talking about parabolas and hyperbolas.

By what references did we (in modern times) get the idea of the foci and directrix? Or was it *rediscovered*? Any sources/references?